# April 5, 2010, a string must convert to date in Java

Tags: java, string, date

I have this code.

```
 String fromDate = "April 5, 2010";
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 java.util.Date dtt;
 try {
       dtt = df.parse(fromDate);
       java.sql.Date ds = new java.sql.Date(dtt.getTime());
       System.out.println(ds);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {}
```

But, this will output to

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "April 5, 2010"
```

Comment: You say your string has the format dd/MM/yyyy which it clearly doesn't . [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can find all possible format 'letters'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fromDate`(April 5, 2010) is not in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

If you change your `formDate` from -

```
String fromDate = "April 5, 2010";
```

to -

```
String fromDate = "5-April-10;
```

Then you can use the following code snippet -

```
String fromDate = "5-April-10";

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy");
convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(fromDate);

System.out.println("Converted Date: " +convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to parse a format with the text written out with spaces and a comma using a format that specifies that only numbers and `/` for separators.  Try using this string in your `SimpleDateFormat` constructor: `"MMM dd, yyyy"`

Answer (score 2):

The format passed in SimpleDateFormat has to match with your input date. Input Date - "April 5, 2010", so the format to parse the input date has to be "MMM dd, yyyy"

Try this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: the format passed in SimpleDateFormat has to match with your input date. Input Date - "April 5, 2010", so the format to parse the input date has to be "MMM dd, yyyy"

Comment: It is useful to give more details in answer. that helps visitors and reviewers.  I copied your comment into answer-- an an example.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to parse a date with DateFormat that is in a different format. You should use SimpleDateFormat and specify the format string that represents what you're parsing.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
Date formatted = formatter.parse(fromDate);
//Whatever you need to do
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code helps

```
String fromDate = "April 5, 2010";
         DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
         java.util.Date dtt;
         try {
               dtt = (Date)df.parse(fromDate);
               java.sql.Date ds = new java.sql.Date(dtt.getTime());
               System.out.println(ds);
               System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(ds));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {}
```